# Code of Java Arrays

Tags: java

I am a beginner in programming. I want some help to understand the following code. Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class SingleDimensionalArray3 {

    static void min(int arr[]) {

        int min = arr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (min > arr[i])
                min = arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(min);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[] = { 123, 432, 1243, 13424, 12323 };
        min(a);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Open a Java book or tutorial and start reading.

Comment: What exactly you don't understand about your code?

Comment: Ok. @krzyk teach me the working of for loop and if condition in this program.

Comment: working of for loop and if condition in this program @PaoloForgia

Comment: @OssamaMemon what about 'if condition'? If your question is how it works please don't ask on stackoverflow but search on google for a documentation (like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) or check out stackoverflow documentation ( http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/118/basic-control-structures/473/if-else#t=201607260633270202089 )

Comment: No @PaoloForgia you didn't get me. I am just asking the working of if and for in this Program. Overall I know what is if and for just can't understand how they work in this particular program.

Answer (score 0):

int min = arr[0]; initializes the first element of array i.e 123 as min
For loop is the comparison between min and other elements. If any other element in the array is smaller then min then its value is assigned to min and finally it prints the min(smallest element in the array)

Comment: `int min = arr[0]; initializes the first element of array` It does not.

Comment: It most certainly doesn't! But...it does initialize the declared integer variable named min with the Array Element contained in arr[0] which happens to be the integer value of: 123